# "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface" even though it is

Tags: java, functional-interface

Okay so I'm feeling pretty dumb here. I ran into this problem in my Eclipse today and for the world I can't figure out what the problem is.

It's very simple. The following compiles:

```
MockCreationListener l = (mock, settings) -> {};
Mockito.framework().addListener(l);
```

The following does not:

```
Mockito.framework().addListener((mock, settings) -> {});
```

I know already that this is some silly thing I overlooked but what is the difference between these two bits of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because [`addListener`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/MockitoFramework.html) accepts a [`MockListener`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/listeners/MockitoListener.html) interface. which is a marker interface with no methods.

As you may know, lambdas can only be converted to interfaces with exactly one abstract method. So Java can't convert your lambda to `MockListener`. Without any other information, it doesn't know what functional interface it should convert your lambda to, so it outputs an error.

Of course, *you* know that it should be `MockCreationListener`, but the compiler can't figure it out just by looking at the context. It could be anything that implements `MockListener` and also accepts two parameters and returns `void`, as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer since you phrased it so much more clearly than my own :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well I solved it.

For posterity the answer is that Mockito.framework().addListener() expects a MockListener interface, not a MockCreationListener.

Why is that important? Because MockCreationListener defines the method being implemented by the lambda and java has no idea that the lambda is also a valid implementation of MockListener - which has no methods.

I'm closing it and apoligies for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: As long as you don't delete it. It's not a waste of time if it helps someone else, also.